# How to attach sources to auto-generated Gradle-based dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA 13.0 in a way that will survive next Gradle projects refresh?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, dependency-management

Is there a simple way to attach sources to auto-generated Gradle-based dependencies with `IntelliJ IDEA 13.0` that won't be erased on next Gradle refresh?

For example, my `build.gradle` has such entry:

```
project(":projectName") {

  dependencies {

    compile files("c:/Program Files (x86)/groovy-2.2.1/embeddable/groovy-all-2.2.1.jar")

    // more stuff here
  }
}
```

Thus when I click `Refresh all Gradle projects`

[image: clicking refresh all Gradle projects]

I get a nice dependency set looking like so:

[image: aut-generated Gradle-based deps]

but there are no sources attached and if I do attach them manually, on next refresh they are erased.

I have sources for many different libraries, sometimes in `jar` file, sometimes directly in the file system (e.g. my groovy install has sources in `c:\Program Files (x86)\groovy-2.2.1\src\`).

Some of the dependencies I use can be downloaded from maven central repo, but in my `build.gradle` all the dependencies are configured to be taken from my local file system.

Thanks!
Konrad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only easy solution is to get the dependencies straight from a Maven repository (either Maven Central or an inhouse repository). If that's not an option for you, you'll have to configure sources via a hook such as `idea.module.iml.withXml` or `idea.module.iml.whenMerged` (after applying the `idea` plugin to `allprojects`). You can find details on these APIs in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) and the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: I was afraid I will have to resort to using the `idea` plugin. Thank you, you saved me a lot of time!